# ClientId of UIComponent class

Tags: jsf

What's a difference between methods `getClientId(FacesContext context)` and `getClientId()`of `UIComponent` class. Why when we written `encode` method we invoke `getClientId(FacesContext context)` not `getClientId()`?
Exmple from core JavaServer Faces 3rd edition:

```
public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
    ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
    String clientId = getClientId(context);
    // Encode input field
    writer.startElement("input", this);
    writer.writeAttribute("name", clientId, null);
    Object v = getValue();
    if (v != null) writer.writeAttribute("value", v, "value");
    Object size = getAttributes().get("size");
    if (size != null) writer.writeAttribute("size", size, "size");
    writer.endElement("input");
}
```

Comment: What exactly is preventing you from reading [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getClientId())?

Comment: @BalusC There is no example of using `getClientId()` in documentation.  It's hard to understand without examples.

Comment: Why didn't you state that in the question? Alas, what part exactly didn't you understood? "EL"?

Comment: @BalusC What specific String this method will be return? Or it's enable EL to access the clientId of a component only. Why then the return type is String rather that void?

Comment: Err, what void method exactly are you talking about? Why should a getter/accessor ever return void? Why should whatever a getter returns not be stated in the method name itself?

Comment: @BalusC I'm understand